# How to remove width and height from image field images in Views?

Tags: views, entities

I'm using Views to generate some HTML, and this includes a field from a Views field.

My problem is, the layout needs the images to be reponsive (height and width based on the parent element), but this is being broken by Views writing in the width and height as HTML attributes which override all the CSS.

---

I've [tried the answer to this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51679/how-to-delete-width-and-height-attributes-from-image-field-for-particular-nodes/51688#51688) which uses `hook_field_attach_view_alter()` to remove the width and height from the output array - but it doesn't work, the width and height are still written into the HTML.

Checking the width and height values at the time `hook_field_attach_view_alter()` is called, it seems it's a timing problem: it looks like this is called before the image preset is applied. E.g. my image preset is 190px x 190px scale and crop: at the time `hook_field_attach_view_alter()` is called, the width and height are the original width and height of the image, then the 190 gets written over whatever changes the hook makes.

Is there another hook I can use for the same effect?

---

I also tried using **Rewrite results** in Views to re-create the image from its component parts. The problem is, it has access to everything *except* the actual image URL or URI:

[image]

Is there a way to access the image URL or URI in the replacement patterns for Views rewrite for an image field?

Comment: Have you tried using a Views template?

Comment: I thought they were for whole views, not for specific field types?

Comment: There are different levels of specificity of views templates. Click the "Theme: Information" link under the advanced settings of your view for more info. There are field-level templates for views.

Answer (score 3):

It feels clumsier than I'd hoped and requires a module, but I found a solution:

1. Install [`image_url_formatter` module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter), which creates an image field display that is just the url but still allows you to choose from available image styles
2. Change the image field in the view to use the new "Image URL" display.
3. Use the Views rewrite feature to rebuild the image (`<img src="[field_image]" alt=... />`).