# Custom view mode issues

Tags: 7, theming, routes, entities

My goal is to switch between different view modes based on the node path (pattern). In my case, the patterns would be:

- dossier/node-alias => default template
- dossier/node-alias/cover => cover template
- dossier/node-alias/abstract => abstract template

I have created the custom view modes with `hook_entity_info_alter` (simplified here to only one custom view mode):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info_alter
 */
function dossier_config_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {

  $entity_info['node']['view modes']['cover'] = array(
    'label' => t('Cover view mode'),
    'custom settings' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

Here is how I declared the path pattern in `hook_menu`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function dossier_config_menu() {

  $items = array();

  // Cover entity view mode
  $items['dossier/%/cover'] = array(
    'title' => 'Default title', // overridden in template.php preprocess_node function
    'page callback' => '_dossier_config_switch_viewmodes',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2), // arguments from uri are 1 => node alias and 2 => cover
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And here is my custom callback:

```
function _dossier_config_switch_viewmodes($alias, $view_mode) {

  // Get the node path based on the alias
  $path = drupal_lookup_path('source', 'dossier/' . $alias);

  // Return the node if the path exists
  if ($path !== FALSE) {

    $node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
    $node_view = node_view(node_load($node->nid), $view_mode);

    return array(
      'content' => array(
        'node' => $node_view,
      ),
    );
  }

  return drupal_not_found();
}
```

It works. However, when looking at these nodes in the custom view modes, I lose the node edition tabs (View, Edit, Translate, etc.) and I also seem to lose all the standard classes that are added to the `<body>` such as `node-type-xxx` or `page-node-12345` etc.

I believe that this is a normal behavior with such a custom callback in `hook_menu` (?). So what would be the right way to achieve what I want?

Any help on that will be highly appreciated! Cheers!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that of course I have 3 different node templates and that I have added the `theme_hook_suggestions` accordingly in my theme `template.php`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to use a custom view mode for your content type?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - yes, as explained, a custom view mode based on the node uri. The last part of my node uri would be the view mode to be used (or I can implement any other logic here but basically `node/node-alias/view-mode`).

Comment: In my question I mention `dossier/node-alias/cover` where "dossier" is a path pattern that I defined for one particular content type, "node-alias" is my node alias and "cover" is the view mode to use. Hope this is clear enough :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for your additional pages should be `node/%node/abstract` and `node/%node/cover` with something like

```
$items['node/%node/abstract'] = array(
  'title callback' => 'node_page_title',
  'title arguments' => array(1),
  'page callback' => 'MODULE_node_view',
  'page arguments' => array('abstract', 1),
  'access callback' => 'MODULE_node_view_access',
  'access arguments' => array('abstract', 1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['node/%node/cover'] = array(
  'title callback' => 'node_page_title',
  'title arguments' => array(1),
  'page callback' => 'MODULE_node_view',
  'page arguments' => array('cover', 1),
  'access callback' => 'MODULE_node_view_access',
  'access arguments' => array('cover', 1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

If you don't want your additional pages to be available as tabs (like View, Edit and Translate), you can probably use `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK`. By doing so, you ensure Drupal knows these pages are below the normal node view page.

`MODULE_node_view($view_mode, $node)` and `MODULE_node_view_access($view_mode, $node)` are your page and access callbacks. They receive the `$node` already loaded (thanks to the `%node` in the menu item path). If you don't have specific access rules (such as restricting access to only certain content type), you can replace the access callback and arguments by `node_access` and `array('view', 1)`.

Given the question, your likely want to automatically create aliases for your nodes so you can use paths like `dossier/node-alias/cover` instead of things like use `node/1234/cover`. You can implement [`hook_path_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_insert/7) and [`hook_path_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_delete/7) to automatically create and delete abstract and cover aliases for any aliased node.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_path_insert().
 */
function MODULE_path_insert($path) {
  // If this is an alias to a node view page
  if (preg_match("/^node\/\d+(\/view)?$/", $path['source'], $matches)) {
    // Create aliases for the supported suffixes.
    foreach (array('/abstract', '/cover') as $suffix) {
      $new_path = array_merge($path, array(
        'source' => $matches[0] . $suffix,
        'alias' => $path['alias'] . $suffix
      ));
      unset($new_path['pid']);
      path_save($new_path);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_path_delete().
 */
function MODULE_path_delete($path) {
  // If this is an alias to a node view page
  if (preg_match("/^node\/\d+(\/view)?$/", $path['source'], $matches)) {
    // Delete aliases for the supported suffixes.
    foreach (array('/abstract', '/cover') as $suffix) {
      $new_path = array_merge($path, array(
        'source' => $matches[0] . $suffix,
        'alias' => $path['alias'] . $suffix
      ));
      unset($new_path['pid']);
      path_delete($new_path);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting all that together! It's the end of the day but I'll test this tomorrow morning, first thing :-)